# １つのページ内に複数のmarquee要素がある場合に、１つのmarquee要素のみをリセットするには

Tags: javascript, html

下記のソースコードは、『RESET』ボタンを押すと”マーキーＡ”と"マーキーＢ"が
ともにリセットするように設定されたものです。
これを"マーキーＡ"のみをリセット("マーキーＢ"は、そのまま流れる)させるには、
どのように書き換えればいいのでしょうか。ご教示ください。

```
 <STYLE type="text/css">
  .form{ 
     display: inline;
       }
 </style>

 <script>
       flag=false;
          function Stop_Start(){
             flag = !flag;
              if(flag) {
                document.getElementById("myMarquee").start(); 
                        }
                  else {
                document.getElementById("myMarquee").stop(); 
                     　 }
                document.myForm.tog.value=flag?"STOP":"START";
                                 }
 </script>

 <MARQUEE id='myMarquee'> 
　　    マーキーＡ(＊リセットする)
　</MARQUEE> 

　　<div>
      <FORM class="form" name="myForm">
        <INPUT type="button" name="tog" value="STOP" onclick="Stop_Start()">
      </FORM>
      <form class="form" >
        <INPUT type="button" value="RESET" ONCLICK="location.reload()"> 
      </form>
    </div>

 <MARQUEE> 
　　    マーキーＢ(＊リセットしない)
　</MARQUEE>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ざっと調べてみると marquee 要素をリセットする手軽な手段はないようです。marquee要素そのものを作りなおすのはどうでしょうか。

```
<script>
function resetMarquee() {
    var oldMarquee = document.querySelector('#myMarquee');
    oldMarquee.parentNode.insertBefore(oldMarquee.cloneNode(true), oldMarquee);
    oldMarquee.parentNode.removeChild(oldMarquee);
}
</script>
...
<input type="button" value="RESET" onclick="resetMarquee()">
```

Comment: バッチリです。見慣れない語句が散りばめられていて、読み取れないですが、うまくいきました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 『リセットボタン』を押すと、『STOP(START)ボタン』の表示が、うまくいかないようです。

Comment: 『トグルボタン』で、いろいろ"条件式"を作って試しましたが、テンポがズレるようです。『STOP(START)ボタン』は、別々に作れば問題はないのですが…

Answer (score 0):

回答をいただいた箇所に下記のように書き足しましたら、『トグルボタン』でもうまくいきました。
ただ、"flag=true(false)"を,"num=1(0)"に変えたらうまくいきませんので、この"flag=true(false)"は
上(function Stop_Start(){})に記述されている"flag=true(false)"と同一のものとして判別されている
のかもしれません。

```
    function resetMarquee() {
        var oldMarquee = document.querySelector('#myMarquee');
        oldMarquee.parentNode.insertBefore(oldMarquee.cloneNode(true), oldMarquee);
        oldMarquee.parentNode.removeChild(oldMarquee);         
     if(flag=true){
　　　         　　　document.myForm.tog.value="STOP";
                flag=false;
                        }
}
     </script>

     <MARQUEE id='myMarquee'> 
    　　    マーキーＡ(＊リセットする)
    　</MARQUEE> 

    　　<div>
          <FORM class="form" name="myForm">
            <INPUT type="button" name="tog" value="STOP" onclick="Stop_Start()">
          </FORM>
          <form class="form" >
            <input type="button" value="RESET" onclick="resetMarquee()">
          </form>
        </div>

     <MARQUEE> 
    　　    マーキーＢ(＊リセットしない)
    　</MARQUEE>
```